# Auto update ssl node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

is there any way to make the node.js server update automatically with the new certificates generated by let's encrypt every 3 months without restarting the service?

My server has a hosting panel that auto manages the certificates, so I can't use the certbot manually.

Currently I have a cron that runs monthly and restarts the server to take the new changes, but sometimes the certificate changes a few days before and my sites and apis stop working until my server restarts. It doesn't seem to me the most optimal solution.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const https = require("https");
const express = require("express");
const helmet = require("helmet");
var cors = require("cors");
const API = require("./index.js");

const hostname = "ENV.HOSTAME";
const httpsPort = ENV.PORT;

const httpsOptions = {
  cert: fs.readFileSync("CERT-PATH"),
  ca: fs.readFileSync("CA-PATH"),
  key: fs.readFileSync("CA-KEY"),
};

const app = express();
app.use(helmet());
app.use(cors());
const httpsServer = https.createServer(httpsOptions, app);

// Parse URL-encoded bodies (as sent by HTML forms)
//app.use(express.urlencoded());

// Parse JSON bodies (as sent by API clients)
app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.redirect("HOSTNAME");
});

app.post("API-ROUTE", async function (req, res) {
  const response = await API(req);
  if (response != "Error") {
    res.status(200).send(response);
  } else {
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Server Error" });
  }
});

httpsServer.listen(httpsPort, hostname);
```

Answer (score 0):

nodejs uses http service and nginx for reverse proxy. When the certificate is updated, there is no need to restart the whole service. Executing `nginx -s reload` works for me.